# Passing data from within a class into def

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, binance

When I run the `binance.py` file, I get an error like the following. I am sending data in class. How do I fix this?

```
import websockets
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager


class BinanceFutures(object):
    print("binance futures class")
    # websocket start
    futures_api_key = "oooo"
    futures_secret_key = "ppppp"
    client = Client(futures_api_key, futures_secret_key)
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    conn_key = bm.start_trade_socket('BNBBTC', process_message)
    bm.start()


    def process_message(self, msg):
        print("message type: {}".format(msg['e']))
        print(msg)
        # do something


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("binance main")
```

The error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binancetest.py", line 6, in <module>
    class BinanceFutures:
  File "binancetest.py", line 13, in BinanceFutures
    conn_key = bm.start_trade_socket('BNBBTC', process_message)
NameError: name 'process_message' is not defined
```

Comment: As you defined `process_message` inside your class, you should refer to it as `self.process_message` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not defining nor using a Python `class` properly.

I think you need to do it like this (untested). I've added an `__init__()` method to initialize the class when an instance of it is created. In particular note how I added `self.` prefix to the `self.process_message` argument being passed to `bm.start_trade_socket()` since it's a method of the `class`.

You may need to make `bm` an instance attribute, too. (i.e. `self.bm` everywhere it's referenced.)

```
import websockets
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager


class BinanceFutures:
    def __init__(self):
        print("binance futures class")
        # websocket start
        futures_api_key = "oooo"
        futures_secret_key = "ppppp"
        client = Client(futures_api_key, futures_secret_key)
        bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
        conn_key = bm.start_trade_socket('BNBBTC', self.process_message)
        bm.start()

    def process_message(self, msg):
        print("message type: {}".format(msg['e']))
        print(msg)
        # do something


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("binance main")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's saying, that you haven't defined the name `process_message`, if you define it somewhere in the class or in the file, the error will stop